# Inconsistent font size for scientific notation in axis

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib, font-size

I'm trying to make a plot for which the x axis will show in scientific notation. The way I found how to do so is to use the `ticklabel_format` function. Unfortunately this does not respect the font size I assign to the numbers shown in the axis, see image below:

[image]

The `1e-12` and `1e4` are displayed in a different font size even though I set equal label sizes.

How could I fix this? (A `MWE` is below)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 10000.0, 10.)
s = np.sin(np.pi*t)*np.exp(-t*0.0001)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=7)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0), labelsize=7)
plt.plot(t,s)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`ticklabel_format` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format), the function does not accept `labelsize` parameter.

You can change the font size using [`matplotlib.rc`](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc):

```
plt.rc('font', size=7)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for larger font sizes (for example 35). The font for the labels stays small.

Comment: @StanleyBak, Call `plt.rc('font', ...)` just after `import` statement. https://i.imgur.com/371NoUz.png

Answer (score 4):

I think this will help you, without change the global setting:

`ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(size)`

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because that scientific representation is not treated as tick label, you can use:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('font', size=7)
```

or

```
matplotlib.rcParams['font.size']=7
```

and remove `labelsize=7` in `ax.tick_params`